# How to remove $$hashKey from objects?

Tags: javascript, object, functional-programming, ramda.js

**[Ramda REPL example](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=let%20tickers%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%24%24hasKey%3A%20%22object%3A280%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20ticker%3A%20%27goog%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%24%24hasKey%3A%20%22object%3A308%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20ticker%3A%20%27goog%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%24%24hasKey%3A%20%22object%3A327%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20ticker%3A%20%27goog%27%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0AR.uniq%28tickers%29%3B%0A%0AR.dropRepeats%28tickers%29%3B%0A%0A%0A)**

Hi, so I have an Array of objects. These objects somehow gain a `$$hashKey`. I need to remove the `$$hashKey` so my drop duplicates or remove uniques logic.

```
let tickers = [
  {
    $$hasKey: "object:280",
    ticker: 'goog'
  },
  { 
    $$hasKey: "object:308",
    ticker: 'goog'
  },
  {
    $$hasKey: "object:327",
    ticker: 'goog'
  }
]

R.uniq(tickers); //-> Returns all instead of 1

R.dropRepeats(tickers); //-> Returns all instead of 1
```

---

I tried this, but then my tickers array ended up with 3 `undefined` values.

```
const removeRepeats = tickers => {
    console.log('removeRepeats', tickers);
    tickers = _.map(tickers, ticker => {
        delete ticker['$$hasKey']; 
    });

    return R.dropRepeats(tickers);
};
```

Comment: Does "ramda" have a **map()**?

Comment: Yes http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map

Comment: What happens if you update removeRepeats with : **tickers = _.map(tickers, ticker => { return {ticker: ticker["ticker"]}; });**

Comment: Haha yes that did work! Lol sorry I see what happened here... I got so tunnel visioned on removing / destroying those `$$hashKey` keys that I forgot I could just do this. Want to post your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try:

```
const removeRepeats = tickers => {
    console.log('removeRepeats', tickers);
    tickers = _.map(tickers, ticker => { return {ticker: ticker["ticker"]}; });
    return R.dropRepeats(tickers);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you really want [`uniq`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#uniq) rather than [`dropRepeats`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#dropRepeats).  `uniq` gives you the collection of different element in a list.  `dropRepeats` simply removes sequential copies of the same value.  (`[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1] => [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`).

To do this, I would think of it as two steps, one to create versions without the offending key (Ramda's [`dissoc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#dissoc) should help with this) and one to reduce the list to the uniq elements.  I might write it like this:

```
let myFunc = R.pipe(R.map(R.dissoc('$$hasKey')), R.uniq);
myFunc(tickers);
```

If you didn't want to simply remove a single property but instead keep a fixed list of them you might do:

```
R.pipe(R.map(R.pick(['ticker', 'prop2', 'prop3'])), R.uniq)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you need both lodash and ramda together. Any of lodash or ramda by itself is enough with one liner

lodash:

```
_.uniqWith(_.map(tickers, (ticker) => _.pick(ticker, ['ticker'])), _.isEqual)
```

ramda:

```
R.uniq(R.map(R.pick(['ticker']))(tickers))
```

or if you want to compare without all properties starting with `$$` (angular internal properties)

lodash:

```
_.uniqWith(_.map(tickers, (ticker) => _.pickBy(ticker, (val, key) => !_.startsWith(key, '$$'))), _.isEqual)
```

ramda:

```
R.uniq(R.map(R.pickBy((v, k) => !k.startsWith('$$')))(tickers))
```